# Multiple h:inputTextarea to single back-end variable

Tags: jsf-2.2, omnifaces

I'm trying to create a comment page with a variable set of comments (layed out via o:tree, thanks BalusC) that anyone can reply to. I'm displaying the h:inputTextArea via p:inplace, so there are multiple textinputareas per page with multiple commandbutton replies. I'm trying to map the command button to a single back-end variable from a specific textinputarea so that every textinputarea isn't processed each time the command button is pressed.

Edit: Code example

```
<o:tree value="#{xPost.post.comments.treeModel}" var="comment" varNode="node">

    <o:treeNode>
        <o:treeNodeItem>
            <p:panel>
                <h:outputText value="#{comment.commentText}" />
                <p:inplace label="Reply">
                    <br/>
                    <p:editor value="#{post.newComment}" />
                    <p:commandButton action="#{post.saveComment('#{comment.ID'})}" value="Comment" ajax="false" />
                </p:inplace>
                <o:treeInsertChildren />
            </p:panel>
        </o:treeNodeItem>
    </o:treeNode>
</o:tree>
```

To add to this, I'm using hibernate validation, which to my knowledge can only validate via annotations:

@NotBlank(message="Please enter a comment.")
@Length(min=1, max=10000, message="A comment must be between 1 and 10,000 characters.")
@SafeHtml(message="Invalid Rich Text.")
private String newComment = "";

So from the code above, when I have 2+ p:editor, each editor is being processed and populating the same back-bean variable. How do I force a commentButton to only validate a specific inputBox/p:editor and set the backing-bean variable.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: One way would be to move the `<h:form>` to inside `<o:treeNodeItem>`.

Comment: My god, it was so simple and it worked. Thank you BalusC.

Comment: Okay, I reposted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give each editor its own form. In other words, move the `<h:form>` from outside the `<o:tree>` to inside the `<o:treeNodeItem>`. This will ultimately render multiple forms with each its own editor and button.

Comment: I just found the primefaces has a component called [Fragment](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/fragment.jsf) that will do essentially what I was looking for, but your solution works without the component.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to provide your source details for people to give you more help
2. In your case, I'm guessing the following should do the trick:

   ```
   <ui:repeat var="comment" ...> // or equivalent like o:tree
     <h:inputText value="#{comment.message} .../>
     <h:commandButton actionListener="#{bean.updateMessage}">
       <f:setPropertyActionListener from="#{comment}" to="#{bean.commentBeingProcessed}"/>
       <!-- Or alternatively, you can set the comment object on to the command button
            and receive it on the server side as event.getComponent().getAttribute("comment")
         <f:attribute name="comment" value="#{comment}"/>
       -->
     </h:commandButton>
   </ui:repeat>
   ```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't think I properly explained the problem. I have edited my post to better reflect my question.